# Windows security warning shows publisher unknown

Tags: flex3, installation, air, digital-certificate

I am developing an AIR application. I am exporting the release build as native installer by signing it with a digital certificate that was bought from TC Trust Center. Following flow happens with the setup.exe created.

- This setup.exe is now uploaded to a host to enable users to download the setup file.
- A user downloads this using browser and double clicks on the downloaded setup.exe.
- Windows shows up a security warning pop up and states that the publisher is unknown.
- After clicking continue, the AIR installer shows up the correct publisher name
- And when the program is installed the control panel also shows up the correct publisher name.

I would like to know why is Windows security warning unable to detect the publisher name? And how can this issue be resolved. Kindly help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Publisher name must not necessarily be taken from the signature. In fact, in Control Panel it's taken from the registry record rather than from the signature, so this is not a proof.

Most likely you needed to include intermediate CA certificates with the signature, and the tool didn't do this automatically.

Open Explorer, and right-click on your setup.exe and invoke Properties dialog. If the signature is present and recognized, Digital Signature tab will appear in the properties. This doesn't mean that the signature is valid, though. You need to go to this Tab and check the certificates used for signing, their status and the certificate chain. The certificate chain must be complete and lead up to recognized root or trusted CA certificate (recognized means that Windows has it in it's trust list).

Comment: Thanks Eugene! I have followed your procedure to open the properties dialog for setup.exe, but could not find Digital Signature tab. Would this mean that the certificate I am using while creating build is not visible till the exe level to OS (it might only be visible till the AIR installer level)? Kindly advice what can be done to have the certificate and the publisher name available at all levels.

Comment: @Goje87 This means that you have signed the applet but not setup.exe. You need to sign setup.exe separately.